# Redirect 301 issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i´m trying to do a 301 redirect in my .htaccess with the following lines:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /oldpage http://www.myhomepage.de/newpage/
```

The problem is, that the redirected url looks like this:

```
http://www.myhomepage.de/newpage/?it=oldpage
```

and that naturally causes a 404 on my site.
Does anybody know, what the problem could be?
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Redirect and RewriteEngine have nothing to do with each other. Using a RewriteRule will solve your problem. Quick question: are you using ProcessWire?

Comment: Yes, i do use processwire

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to use the [Redirects](http://modules.processwire.com/modules/process-redirects/) or [Jumplinks](http://modules.processwire.com/modules/process-jumplinks/) modules?

Comment: If you're not going to be doing many redirects, however, I'd recommend you use `mod_rewrite` instead - my answer below should work for you.

Comment: I think the Module jumplinks does it, Mike. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^oldpage$ newpage? [R=301,L]
```

The question mark at the end of the destination will tell it to use a blank query string.

The above assume the pages are on the same domain. But if you're moving to another domain, this should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^oldpage$ http://newdomain.tld/newpage? [R=301,L]
```